# What Kind of pre-processing techniques can I apply to make an object more clear?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I applied few techniques of denoising on MRI images and could not realize what techniques are applicable on my data to make the cartilage object more clear. First I applied Contrast-limited adaptive histogram equalization (CLAHE) with this function:

```
J = adapthisteq(I)
```

But I got a white image. This is original image and manual segmentation of two thin objects(cartilage):
[image]

And then I read a paper that they had used some preprocessing on microscopy images, such as: Anisotropic diffusion filter(ADF), then, K-SVD algorithm, and then Batch-Orthogonal Matching Pursuit (OMP). I applied the first two and the output is as following:
[image]

It seems my object is not clear. It should be brighter than other objects. I do not what kind of algorithms are applicable to make the cartilage objects more clear. I really appreciate any help.

**Extended:**
This is the object:[image]

Comment: Could you manually edit a picture to show what you are after (circle in paint or flood fill in photoshop or something).  I think I know what you are after, but not positive.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear I just want to intensity become clearer. and and can have that area more clear and separable. I cannot draw a line, because I have many images

Comment: Oh i just meant for us on SO.  Just to show us what exactly you are looking for.  I am pretty sure I know what the cartilage is in that image, but am not positive.

Comment: Is your second image (the one you manually segmented) all of the cartilage in that image?!  I was under the impression that all of the light grey area objects were cartilage...

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear Thanks a lot for helping me, I edited the question, and added image with ROI

Comment: Oh my... that is significantly harder than I originally understood what you were after

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear what can I do? what do you suggest?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear One thing is that I will apply another algorithm to do the segmentation, but before sending to that I wanted to do clean up on images and make cartilage a bit more clearer and remove other parts that makes the segmentation difficult.

Comment: Well that is kinda the trick isn't it.  The only way to improve or allow segmentation is to find a uniqueness about the cartilage that you can accentuate non-uniformly across the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited (now knowing exactly what you are looking for)

The differences between your cartilage and the surrounding tissue is very slight and for that reason I do not think you can afford to do any filtration.  What I mean by this is that the two things that I can kinda catch with my eye is that the edge on the cartilage is very sharp (the grey to black drop-off), and also there seems to be a texture regularity in the cartilage that is smoother than the rest of the image.  To be honest, these features are incredibly hard to even pick out by eye, and a common rule of thumb is that if you can't do it with your eye, vision processing is going to be rough.

I still think you want to do histogram stretching to increase your contrast.

1:In order to do a clean global contrast stretch you will need to remove bone/skin edge/ whatever that line on the left is from the image (bright white).  To do this, I would suggest looking at the intensity histogram and setting a cut-off after the first peak (make sure to limit this so some value well above what cartilage could be in case there is no white signal).  After determining that value, cut all pixels above that intensity from the image.

2:There appears to be low frequency gradients in this image (the background seems to vary in intensity), global histogram management (normalization) doesn't handle this well, CLAHE can handle this if set up well. But a far simpler solution worth trying is just hitting the image with a high pass filter as this will help to remove some of those (low frequency) background shifts. (after this step you should see no bulk intensity variation across the image.

3: I think you should try various implementations of histogram stretching, your goal in your histogram stretch implementation is to make the cartilage look more unique in the image compared to all other tissue.

This is by far the hardest step as you need to actually take a stab at what makes that tissue different from the rest of the tissue.  I am at work, but when I get off, I will try to brainstorm some concepts for this final segmentation step here.  In the meantime, what you want to try to identify is anything unique about the cartilage tissue at this point.  My top ideas are cylindrical style color gradient, surface roughness, edge sharpness, location, size/shape

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendation. I will apply all of them and let you know. What I did till now is : 1)normalization,2)noise removal (median filtering), 3)histogram matching, 4) CLAHE, I am not sure how much I am doing correct. My question is does it affect to do normalization first and then remove noise or vice versa? thanks

Comment: depends if the noise can be removed before normalization.  In this case (using a median filter) filtration can indeed be done before normalization.  Depending on your normalization techniques though this shouldn't make a big difference.

Comment: Well wait, I may be misunderstanding you.  If your normalization is (contrast stretching) then it is very important to do noise filtration first.  Also, several of your steps are redundant.  CLAHE is a form of localized contrast stretching

Comment: Before any filtering, image intensity values should be scaled first. This is because each image has different intensity range values that affects the filtering